# Tinymce node content changed

Tags: javascript, events, tinymce, rte, mutation-observers

I'm trying to fire an event every time a node has been changed.

Basically I need to fire it when an empty line (node) is no longer empty.

In the documentation I found only change method, but that doesn't fire every time immediately.

Is there any other event I can listen to?

Answer (score 1):

You can assing a mutation observer on the tinymce editor dom and listen for changes. Use the tinymce configuration parameter setup and add a init handler to observe the dom right from the start:

```
setup : function(ed) {

    ed.on('init', function(e){
        // MutationObserver
        var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
        if (typeof MutationObserver != 'undefined')
        {   
            // select the target node
            var targets = ed.getDoc().querySelector('body');

            // create an observer instance
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                    // do your magic here!!!
                });    
            });

            // configuration of the observer:
            var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

            // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
            observer.observe(targets, config);
        }
        // fallback for older browsers
        else
        {
            $(ed.getBody()).bind('DOMNodeChanged', function(e) {
               // do your magic here !
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You might need to configure the observer to your needs.
Here is a helpful page about mutation observers: https://addyosmani.com/blog/mutation-observers/.
Do not use mutation events because they are deprecated.

You may use mutation events as a fallback for browsers that do not support the observers (see code above).

Comment: Thank you. How is it with cross browser compatibility?

Comment: mutation observers are a HTML5 feature and will work with all newer browsers. See a table reagarding this issue here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver

Comment: that's kinda problem. I need something that will work at least for IE9.

Comment: in this case you will have to use dom mutation events as a fallback (see my updated answer)